# print gridviews, datagrids, or datatables

Tags: vb.net, printing

I'm looking for a solution to implement in web apps where I have the option to see a print preview or print either a gridview, datagrid, or datatable or export it to word or excel. What's the best method to do this or has someone written a class that does this, and does it well (I've seen many examples, but many still have errors)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could look into converting your DataTable's to Table's in HTML then using the resources for setting up Media types to format it for a print job.  Thought behind this response would be this link:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/17049-printing-in-html/